# Call APIs from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, oauth

I am trying to call [Directory APIs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user) from my GAE application in JSP. The application is already running on AppSpot. I'd like to retrieve all organizational units that a user belong to. Unfortunately I get 404 code while making the request and I have no idea why.

```
    ArrayList<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
    scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user");
    AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
    AppIdentityService.GetAccessTokenResult accessToken = appIdentity.getAccessToken(scopes);

    URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/myuser@mygoogleappsdomain.com");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken.getAccessToken());

    if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        out.print("OK");
    }
    else {
        out.print(connection.getResponseCode());
    }
```

As you can imagine this code snippet prints 404. Basically I am following an [example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/) that is available on the GAE documentation. What am i doing wrong? Thank you.

EDIT: If I just call one of the following URLs I get a 403 status code. Is there anything wrong with my OAuth authentication?

https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=mydomain
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users

Comment: Can't see what's wrong with your code, but you should really consider using the [Java client library](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/libraries) rather than making the connections yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only provides app identity. You will also need to get authorisation from user to get access to their directory info.

If you follow the link you provided you get to the point that states: [`All requests to the Directory API must be authorized by an authenticated user`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing).

So you will need to send your users through a OAuth 2 authentication + authorization procedure, where you will ask them for Directory API access. If you only need a read-only access to list of users then you will need to request a `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly` scope.

Comment: That sounds quite strange to me. I mean, I am the domain administrator, I don't need user permissions in order to access their information because I can already do that through the admin panel. Perhaps I need to gather those information with an admin account?

Comment: Your app needs approval from you to be able to access Directory API.

Comment: Afaik, there is no implicit link between accounts: you being admin of your app and then using the app does not give app implicit access to all APIs via your account. You as a user still need to go through OAuth procedure and give the app explicit permission to access APIs on your behalf.